# Show you can't fit a more expensive box into a cheaper one

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, puzzle

Suppose you want to send a package (a box (an orthohedron)). The delivery company tells you the price of the package will be the sum of the dimensions of the box, i.e., if it has sides $a \times b \times c$ then it will cost $a+b+c$ $ to send. Show you can't fit a more expensive box into a cheaper one.

**NOTE**: I have tried a few different approaches and I think I have a proof for the planar case, though rather complicated, but still should be adaptable to the 3D case. What I'm looking for (mostly) are elegant solutions or ideas that don't involve a lot of computations / analysis tricks.

**NOTE 2**: It's easy to show, however, that you can achieve a better price for your mailing with *several* packages. This is not the case here, we just consider exactly one inner box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an old problem. Let $B$ be a box, and define, for $r>0$,
the $r$-neighbourhood $B^{(r)}$ to be the set of points of
Euclidean distance at most $r$ from $B$. If $B_1\subseteq B_2$
then $B_1^{(r)}\subseteq B_2^{(r)}$. Now consider the volumes
of the $B_i^{(r)}$ as $r\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't understand how letting $r$ go to infinity solves this problem.

Comment: Me neither, I guess... I'm sorry if it's obvious.

Comment: The volume will be $abc + 2(ab+ac+bc)R+\color{red}{(a+b+c)}\pi R^2+\frac43\pi R^3$. When comparing the two boxes, we can ignore the identical cubic parts and then for $R\gg 0$, the quadratic parts dominate the volume.